# How do I sign in with email and password via PHP and obtain the JWT token?

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I can't figure out how to authenticate a user from PHP. The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start?authuser=0) demonstrate a signin via javascript where the user email and password are in plain text (`firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`) and I am not sure how this works in term of security when people can just view the source code and get the login info.

I have tried looking up libraries, such as [this](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/), but there doesn't seem to be any way I can authenticate a user to start interacting with the database.

Currently, the security rules are as followed (which is the minimum, allows read/write from any user that logged in):

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

My questions are:

**1. How do I authenticate a user with email & password from PHP, then obtain a token that can further be used by javascript?**

**2. How exactly does Firebase authentication work before I have the sufficient permission to interact with the tools, such as Firestore?** *(To the best of my understanding, I assume it works by first logging in from the serverside to obtain a token with details, then javascript can use that token to safely interact with Firestore, but I am not sure if this is what is expected.)*

**3. Why is logging (using plain email and password) in using javascript even a thing? Wouldn't it mean everyone can see all the credentials?**

**4. For javascript libraries that interact with the server like this, how can the server (Firestore) prevent data modification from evil doers through the Console? Once they are logged in, they can simply send commands from the Console to the server because it's just all javascript. Am I correct?** *(Once you have logged in, of course)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first start with saying that Firebase isn't meant to be accessed on behalf of a user from a backend service (at least it's what I believe). The Client SDKs are meant to be used from within user-facing client application, the Server/Admin SDKs are meant to be used for background and maintenance jobs (if Firebase Cloud Functions aren't enough).

> **How do I authenticate a user with email & password from PHP, then obtain a token that can further be used by javascript?**

A "Sign in with email and password" functionality is currently (I'm going back and forth in my head if it should ) not available in the [unofficial Firebase SDK for PHP](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php), but you can do it by using a custom token:

```php
<?php

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;

$email = '...';
$password = '...';
$serviceAccount = '/path/to/service-account.json';

$factory = (new Factory())->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount);

$auth = $factory->createAuth();

$userRecord = $auth->verifyPassword($email, $password);
$customToken = $auth->createCustomToken($userRecord->uid);
```

You can then pass the custom token to your JavaScript application and use [`Auth.signInWithCustomToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#sign-inwith-custom-token) with it.

> **How exactly does Firebase authentication work before I have the sufficient permission to interact with the tools, such as Firestore?**

On the server-side, a Service Account is used to authenticate requests to the Firebase APIs. If you create such Service Account credentials as described in [the official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk), you can use it to initialize a Server SDK with it and access your Firebase with no restrictions. If you're then performing actions on behalf of a user, you have to ensure yourself that the user has previously authenticated with your custom application.

An "as user" API connection currently is not available in the SDK as well as Firestore support, but I'm working on it.

On the client-side, a Client SDK is initialized with an API key (which is not a secret, you can find it e.g. in the HTML source code of a Firebase-enabled web application), but the application cannot interact with Firebase at all without authentication of any kind, at least [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth). When authenticated anonymously, it's the job of the different kind of security rules (Storage, Realtime Database, Firestore, ...) to ensure that anonymous users can't mess with other data than their's alone.

> **Why is logging (using plain email and password) in using javascript even a thing? Wouldn't it mean everyone can see all the credentials?**

I'm not sure I fully understand this question, but you're right - if secrets are logged, that's a problem, but in any environment. If an application developer pushes an email/password combination to the logs before passing the credentials to e.g `Auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword()`, then everybody that can see the logs will be able to catch them. If you found such log-statements in a library, you should absolutely notify the library developers so that they can fix that.

I'm almost sure that you already knew that and that you meant something else, I just wanted to put it out there for completenesses sake ^^.

> **For javascript libraries that interact with the server like this, how can the server (Firestore) prevent data modification from evil doers through the Console? Once they are logged in, they can simply send commands from the Console to the server because it's just all javascript. Am I correct?**

Once logged in as an Application user, that user will only be able to access the parts of your application that are enabled for them via the defined security rules. For the security rule you gave, you're right: this is too permissive, and as long as someone is authenticated, they could read and write as long as they are authenticated at all (so, this would only prevent access to your application *without* authentication.

If you wanted to ensure that users can only see and change their own data, you could use a rule like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents/{userId} {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

This was just an example, the [official Firestore Security Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview) is far more comprehensive than I could ever be ^^.

Application users can neither log in to the Firebase Console of your project nor with the Firebase CLI tools.

Comment: kreait/firebase-php issued a release in March, v4.41.0 that removed support for `Auth::verifyPassword()` and now requires custom authentication flows